# How does code typed in Arduino IDE runs on a nodemcu?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu, iot, firmware

I actually have a series of questions regarding Nodemcu and esp8266.

1. How does code typed in Arduino IDE run on Nodemcu?
2. What firmware is present on the nodemcu?
3. How do I upload the above firmware on esp8266-01 module?
4. I want my esp8266-01 module to work with a Lilypad Arduino. So this is the way I want it to work: Lilypad Ardiuno has acquires some data using a sensor. It wants to post this data to a server on internet. So to do the job it uses a ESP8266-01. Will the configuration work?

Comment: NodeMCU name has a development board and a firmware. both can be used independently. maybe you have the NodeMcu firmware on the NodeMcu board. NodeMcu firmware with the Lua language will not work with Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how does code typed in Arduino IDE runs on Nodemcu

The IDE runs the compiler which turns the C into assembly and then machine code.  That is then uploaded to the ESP8266.

> what firmware is present on the nodemcu.

The code that you just wrote and uploaded.

> i want my esp8266-01 module to work with a Lilypad Arduino .So this is the way I want it to work Lilypad Ardiuno has acquires some data using a sensor it wants the post this data to a server on internet.So to do the job it uses a ESP8266-01.So will the configuration work?

Sure, if you program it to do that.  Two choices:

1. Use the AT firmware on the ESP-01 (installed by default)
2. Write custom firmware (as above) for the ESP-01 to do what you want.

Comment: Thankyou so much @Majenko , it would be very kind of you if you point me to some references for question no. three.thankyou once again .it was very helpful

Comment: Google: Arduino ESP8266 AT and you'll find your answers.